# Provisioning Poly VVX250 with Google Voice does nothing

Tags: voip, google-voice, polycom

I'm starting a small business and need a phone at the front desk. I purchased a poly VVX250 because, according to Google, it is one of the only phones supported by Google Voice.

I'm following the extremely simple and sparse instructions on [setting up void desk phones for your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9250113?hl=en&ref_topic=9038926), but after it tells me the phone will reboot, it never does and nothing ever happens.

I updated the firmware to make it OBi `6.3.1.1`, but that didn't have any effect.

Notably, there is an error under `Customization Status` in the phone's Product Information section:

```
Contacting Server: Networking is not
```

(it cuts off and I don't know how to see the rest of the message)
I don't think the Customization Status is the problem, but I wonder if it's symptomatic of another connection issue. Is it possible the server that needs to be contacted is down? Or something of that nature?